# 2019 Higgs Boson Mass?

Tags: experimental-physics, mass, measurements, higgs, large-hadron-collider

Wiki, based on the [2018](https://journals.aps.org/prd/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevD.98.030001) Particle Data Group, gives the Higgs boson mass as $125.18 \pm 0.16$ GeV$/c^2$. OK.

However, [2017 ATLAS](https://atlas.cern/updates/physics-briefing/new-atlas-measurement-higgs-boson-mass) gives a combined value of $124.98 \pm 0.28$ GeV$/c^2$.

So what is the 2019 latest result, PDG 2018, 2017 ATLAS, or something else? Is it $124.988063...$ GeV?

Comment: *Is it 124.988063...GeV?* I’m pretty sure that the Higgs mass has *not* been measured to one part in a billion.

Comment: Thanks G. Smith! Good to know. Still, would be interested if any published newer results than 2017 ATLAS... e.g. https://home.cern/news/press-release/physics/lhc-experiments-present-new-higgs-results-2019-eps-hep-conference (but couldn't find an answer)

Comment: There is also the CMS experiment measurement  and a combined statistically value should be found in the particle data group tables, which would be the present accepted value. One should not rely on wikipedia.

Comment: @anna v Thank you...however, Wiki IS from the 2018 particle data group tables. I have amended my question to make that clear. My question, i.e. what are the very latest results, still stands...

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the link you gave, the [combined higgs mass is](https://journals.aps.org/prd/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevD.98.030001) given as 125.18 +/-16. Differs from  just Atlas. They have combined all possible seen channels and experiments to get at this accuracy.

To see part of the complexity have a look at [this talk at CERN](https://indico.cern.ch/event/686555/contributions/3028073/attachments/1683947/2706879/201810August_ICHEP_HiggsPlenary_3.pdf). It is not simple.

Comment: Thanks, good read...still, what I was asking...is there any newer/reputable/multi-channel results than the 2018 PDG re Higgs Boson Mass. I thought there might be, given that 2019 CERN press release. If no, (which is what I think you are saying), fine, 2018 result is it, with update in 2020 I guess. Cheers.

Comment: Yes, it is a long shutdown and they have not come out with new analysis for the Higgs. For some reason the pdg site in the US is not working. I found the mirror site in England works .http://durpdg.dur.ac.uk/lbl/.